# advice on PhD proposal

Tags: education, operator-algebras, advice, research

I am a PhD  student in pure mathematics, and I want to work in the field of $C^*$-algebras and operator algebras
I am looking for a relatively comprehensive view of this subject. For example,

1. what are the mainstream areas?
2. Who works on essential topics in the field?
3. What are the main questions in these areas?
4. ...?

Of course, I like the geometric representation of these $C^*$-algebras and their applications in quantum physics, but by consulting with others, it's hard for a doctorate.
I'm glad if anyone can introduce a resource or something that will increase my information.

PS : This question is my first question; maybe I have not entirely complied with the rules

Comment: It's very rare that I get the opportunity to say this on here, but this actually might be a better question to ask the nice folks over at mathoverflow.net -- they're basically just like us here except with a focus on research-level mathematics.

Comment: @JackCrawford thank you very much. I was also hesitant to ask this question here or not. Thanks for the guide

Comment: I would suggest that you ask your PhD advisor instead. Neither here nor MathOverflow is a good fit for this question

Comment: @davidlowryduda, thank you very much